# Temporary lock for a door

Tags: lock

Is there a way to lock a door temporarily without making modifications to the door or its frame; or making minimal modifications like screw holes. I don't want to be cutting big circular holes in the door.

The door swings inward and is made of wood.

Comment: I've used a 2x4 across the back of the door, screwed into the frame.  Fairly common during construction before lock hardware and trim has been installed.

Comment: @Tyson I need to open the door from the outside.

Comment: So... there is no existing hardware at all, just a hinged door with no holes?

Comment: @JimmyFix-it There is an existing lock but other people have keys to that lock. I want to be able to lock the door so that only I can enter.

Comment: Does the door open outward or inward? If outward, is there anything next to the door that a chain or bar can be passed through? If inward, is there anything on the door that a chain or bar can be passed through?

Comment: Inward swing residential ? Or outward swing commercial?  Single or double? And how tight is the fit in the frame?  Any reason to not just change the key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about a door knob lock-out device? No holes or screws required:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If this is your primary issue:

> There is an existing lock but other people have keys to that lock. I
>   want to be able to lock the door so that only I can enter.

Then the obvious, and in my opinion the best, solution is to simply get the existing locks re-keyed.

Comment: As I said in my question: I want to be able to lock the door WITHOUT MAKING MODIFICATIONS TO THE DOOR. The existing lock must stay the way it is.

Comment: @TylerDurden - My suggestion stands as a sensible solution to your issue. It does not entail changes to the door or the door frame as you specified in your question.

Answer (score 0):

"There is an existing lock but other people have keys to that lock. I want to be able to lock the door so that only I can enter."

**Take away the keys that the other people have.**

Other than that - you would need to have a means of attaching to the door a lock - screws in the door, a hasp on the frame .. and then attach a lock to that .. but pretty useless if someone wants to get in they will rip it off by some means - unless the bolts  go through the door and through the frame.