# Hardware to lock an internally opening door from the outside

Tags: lock, security

**Key Question:** How to lock an internally opening door from the outside.  I know that I could use a security hasp (image) or I could change the doornob but I am trying to avoid these two options.

[image]

**Why can't I change the door nob:** Rented apartment.  Door knobs have centuries of paint over them.  Would probably need to touch up paint to do a good job.

**What are the problems with a security hasp:**

- Ugly
- Sharp
- Makes noise when you open/close the door

**Background:** Hiring a cleaning lady, want to prevent her from entering our offices.  Offices have doors that open inwards.

---

**Edit:** Current door knob looks like this:

[image]

Comment: possibly duplicate of this: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/109265/23920

Comment: Why the down vote?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a doorknob lockout device would work:

[image]

Comment: The door itself doesn't have a lock on it.  This looks like it takes advantage of the existing lock on the door.

Comment: Dude, in your question you stated "Why can't I change the door nob: Rented apartment. Door knobs have centuries of paint over them. Would probably need to touch up paint to do a good job." Anybody would presume from your statement that the door has a knob-type lock/latch on it...

Comment: Sorry, should have specified in my question that my current door knobs don't have a lock.  If they did, I would just use that.  I edited my question with a picture of the style of door knob.

Comment: @sixtyfootersdude so to be clear, there's no keyholes like shown in your picture?

Comment: This is a device that fits over the doorknob itself and just prevents anyone from being able to turn the knob. It's basically a metal, locking version of a child-proof doorknob cover. Great solution, since it doesn't require drilling any holes, is entirely temporary, and doesn't impede anyone's ability to exit the room if necessary (eg: fire).

Comment: @Niall - Not in the door knob itself.  There is a keyhole several cm below the door knob.

Comment: @sixtyfootersdude  then presumably there's a sashlock in the door? You can try and get a key for that. On a new lock you would simply need to find the key number and pick one up. If it's very old then you might need to get a lock-smith to make one. Failing that you could replace the sashlock with a new one (would force you to take off the door handle but you putting it back in exactly the same spot so paint shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should install keyed surface mount deadbolts, so they can be opened from the inside without the key. Otherwise, it's an extreme fire hazard.[image]

Comment: Trying to avoid drilling large holes in the door.  Would like something that is easily removable when we move.